# Openssl installation calling functions from another openssl installation

Tags: c, ssl

Odd situation here...

On Centos5, we have an app that uses 2 different, specific versions of openssl (1.0.1h and 0.9.8u to be specific) to make requests to servers. We build both versions ourselves and install them to a non-standard location (/opt/foo/first-openssl and /opt/foo/other-openssl for example)

The config/build/install commands look like this:

```
$ ./openssl-1.0.1h/Configure --prefix=/opt/foo/first-openssl --with-krb5-flavor=MIT --with-krb5-dir=/opt/foo/krb5 shared zlib enable-rc5 enable-camellia enable-capieng enable-cms enable-mdc2 enable-idea enable-experimental enable-seed no-asm linux-generic64 -m64 -Wl,-rpath=/opt/foo/zlib/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/foo/krb5/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/foo/first-openssl/lib
$ make depend && make
$ make install

$ ./openssl-0.9.8u/Configure --prefix=/opt/foo/other-openssl --with-krb5-flavor=MIT --with-krb5-dir=/opt/foo/krb5 shared zlib enable-rc5 enable-camellia enable-capieng enable-cms enable-mdc2 enable-idea enable-experimental enable-seed no-asm linux-generic64 -m64 -Wl,-rpath=/opt/foo/zlib/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/foo/krb5/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/foo/other-openssl/lib
$ make depend && make
$ make install
```

However, I'm hitting a segfault later on because the app calls an other-openssl function which in turn calls a function in the first openssl's compiled library for crpyto. From gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x2aaab6dfb940 (LWP 15836)]
0x00002aaab1905bd4 in engine_unlocked_finish () from /opt/foo/first-openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00002aaab1905bd4 in engine_unlocked_finish () from /opt/foo/first-openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#1  0x00002aaab1905cc1 in ENGINE_finish () from /opt/foo/first-openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0x00002aaab1919895 in EVP_DigestInit_ex () from /opt/foo/first-openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#3  0x00002aaab701f90b in ssl3_connect () from /opt/foo/other-openssl/lib/libssl.so
#[snip]
```

But everything looks to be linked properly in /opt/foo/other-openssl/lib...

```
# ldd /opt/foo/other-openssl/lib/libssl.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd11fd000)
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /opt/foo/other-openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00002ab91fbd3000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /opt/foo/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00002ab91ff7f000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /opt/foo/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00002ab9201d5000)
    libcom_err.so.3 => /opt/foo/lib/libcom_err.so.3 (0x00002ab9204c0000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /opt/foo/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00002ab9206c4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002ab920915000)
    libz.so.1 => /opt/foo/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00002ab920b19000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002ab920d35000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /opt/foo/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00002ab92108e000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00002ab92129a000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00002ab92149d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000036b6a00000)
```

I do see quite a bit of:

```
gcc: -rpath: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: /opt/foo/lib: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: -rpath: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: /opt/foo/other-openssl/lib: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

While running the commands for 'other-openssl' that I don't see for 'first-openssl'

Am I doing something stupid with how I build these libraries? We don't do any customization/patching, and I can't figure out for the life of me why the 'other-openssl' library is calling out to the 'first-openssl' library.